# Adding odd numbers in Bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to create a program that will add odd numbers given an user input. So far this is what I have. It's failing, and I am not sure where to go from here.

```
echo "How many numbers would you like to add?"
read n
i=1
sum=0
echo "Odd numbers are:"
while [ i -le $n ]
do
    odd=(2*i-1)
    echo -n $odd
    sum=(sum+odd)
    ((i++))
done
echo "Sum is: $sum"
```

Comment: How is it failing?  What's the error?

Comment: `odd=(2*i-1)` should be `odd=$((2*i-1))` and likewise for `sum=(sum+odd)`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get it to work with this script:

```
echo "How many numbers would you like to add?"
read n

echo "Odd numbers are:"
let i=1
let sum=0
while [ $i -le $n ]
do
    let odd=2*i-1
    echo "$odd"
    sum=$((sum+odd))
    ((i++))
done

echo "Sum is: $sum"
```

There were some places where the syntax had to be corrected.

For example, the syntax for evaluating arithmetical expressions is `$((expr))`.

And the `$` might be needed in front of some variables.

Here is the output of the script:

```
% chmod +x script.sh
% ./script.sh
How many numbers would you like to add?
5
Odd numbers are:
1
3
5
7
9
Sum is: 25
```

Comment: Got it so, expressions always have to have $(()). Am I getting that correct?

Comment: Good question! There are many ways of evaluating arithmetic expressions in Bash. We can use double parentheses, e.g. `echo $((x+y))`. When declaring a variable we can use `declare -i num=x+y`. When declaring a variable we can also use `let num=x+y`.

Comment: The `$((...))` syntax is called _arithmetic context._ Without this, the shell does not perform addition or multiplication, `i=i+1` will simply assign the literal string `i+1` to the variable `i`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a `for` loop

```
#! /bin/bash

echo "How many numbers would you like to add?"
read n

echo "Odd numbers are:"
for (( i=1; i<=2*n; sum+=i,i+=2 )); do 
    echo $i
done
echo "Sum is: $sum"
```